# How to use variable or data to change left or right value

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have two animations which are practically identical... the difference between them is "left vs right" positioning. I would like to reuse the first block of code for both .forward and .backward... I'm guessing this could be done with the use of a data or maybe variables, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

thanks for the help

```
$('.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});
$('.hover-area').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.forward').stop()
        .animate({right:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
        .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
},function() {
    $(this).find('.forward').stop()
        .animate({right:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
        .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
});

$('.backward').css({opacity:0, left:0});
$('.hover-area').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.backward').stop()
        .animate({left:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
        .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
},function() {
    $(this).find('.backward').stop()
        .animate({left:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
        .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new jQuery function and pass variables for each difference between the two segments on code.

```
$.fn.setupAnimation = function(selector, direction) {
    return this.hover(function() {
        var startData = {};
        startData[direction] = 20;

        $(this).find(selector).stop()
            .animate(startData, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
            .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
    }, function() {
        var startData = {};
        startData[direction] = 0;

        $(this).find(selector).stop()
            .animate(startData, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
            .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
    });
}

$('.hover-area').setupAnimation('.forward', 'right');
$('.hover-area').setupAnimation('.backward', 'left');
```

Comment: Thanks... I will give her a go and get back to ya